# How do I force a reducer in cascading?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cascading

To gain some of the benefits only possible with reducers and not mappers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer in Google Groups:

Use a `GroupBy` which invariable will use a reducer when performing the grouping:

```
previousPipe = new GroupBy(previousPipe); //this does a Group on Fields.All
```

Reducing Number of Files (another alternative with less coupling)

```
previousPipe = new GroupBy(previousPipe, new Fields("rand"), 
               new RandonNumGen(Fields.Args));
```

Where new RandonNumGen(Fields.Args) is a function you build from `Function` to create a new Fields("rand") that creates temporary random number (temporary meaning you drop the field later).

For more information check this [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/cascading-user/_wI55ppa5zE) thread: